# React Not editable inputs from Child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I've faced the problem here which is that I cant edit my inputs , I've tried `defaultValue` but I want this to happen with `value`. How Could I Fix this and what's the cause of it?

```
interface ChildProps {
  name: string;
  onChange: (newName: string) => void;
  onDelete: () => void;
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildProps> = React.memo(
  ({ name, onChange, onDelete }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>);});

function ParentComponent() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(["First", "Second"]);

  const onNameChange = (index: number, newName: string) => {
    const mutatedNames = [...names];
    mutatedNames[index] = newName;
    setNames(mutatedNames);
    console.log(mutatedNames);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={index}
          name={name}
          onChange={() => onNameChange(index, name)}
          onDelete={() => {
            setNames((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
          }}/>))}</div>);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you aren't using the new value from the child component, so it is working you are just always passing the value from the parent.

Try this out:

```
interface ChildProps {
  name: string;
  onChange: (newName: string) => void;
  onDelete: () => void;
}

const ChildComponent: React.FC<ChildProps> = React.memo(
  ({ name, onChange, onDelete }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}/>
      </div>);});

function ParentComponent() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(["First", "Second"]);

  const onNameChange = (index: number, newName: string) => {
    const mutatedNames = [...names];
    mutatedNames[index] = newName;
    setNames(mutatedNames);
    console.log(mutatedNames);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {names.map((name, index) => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={index}
          name={name}
          onChange={(newName) => onNameChange(index, newName)}
          onDelete={() => {
            setNames((prev) => prev.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
          }}/>))}</div>);}
```